# How do I scroll the iPhone UIPickerView from the last item to the first and continue forever?

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I want my UIPickerView to rotate to the beginning of the list when it is scrolled past the bottom. How do I do this? Basically, I want the functionality of the UIDatePicker when it scrolls the hours/minutes/seconds continuously.

I'm assuming I could just return an extremely large number from the numberOfComponentsInPickerView and then the actual titleForRow with a modulus of the number, but I think there must be a better way. Plus, I'm not sure how it is handled when the wheel starts since I can't return a negative number and it doesn't normally scroll backwards.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: UIPickerView doesn't support this, if that's what your asking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this idea would work](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/01/longer-spinning-blurring.html) - just keep the user in the middle of the wheel so it has the sensation of staying on the same wheel.

Comment: A comment from the article mentions overlaying a UIView with animation: "They're overlaying the picker wheels with animation frames, giving the illusion of fast spinning."

Comment: Yeah - I used the exact same ideas as them and I was able to get a simulated continuous wheel. Clever idea of theirs. I didn't need to simlulate fast spinning but that's also very clever.